# Is $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$ neither an open set nor a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

The subset of the Euclidean space $R^2$ that I'm having trouble with determining whether it's closed or not is $A:=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$.
I'm trying to use the proposition that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I currently proved that $A$ is not open, but when you think about $A^c$, the problematic parts are (n,m) ($n\in \mathbb{N}$, $m\notin Q$). 
Whenever you take a open ball from this point, you can always find (n,p) ($n\in \mathbb{N}$, $p\in\mathbb{Q}$) within the ball since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. 
So I thought that any open ball based on this point can't be in $A^c$. From here I concluded that A is not closed either. Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, that's correct!

Another way to show that it's not closed, which might be easier, is the following: can you think of a sequence of points in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$ which converges to some point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which *isn't* in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$? This boils down to finding a sequence of rationals which approach an irrational, and at the end of the day is basically identical to your proof, but might be intuitively easier.

---

As a side note: you might find it interesting to know that there are classifications of sets in topological spaces which go beyond just open and closed; the most common one is the [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy). We start with open and closed sets at the bottom layer of this hierarchy; the next layer consists of *countable unions of closed sets* and *countable intersections of open sets* (called "$F_\sigma$" and "$G_\delta$", or "$\Sigma^0_2$" and "$\Pi^0_2$," respectively). It turns out that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is $F_\sigma$ but not $G_\delta$. And the hierarchy goes beyond this, and in fact classifies [all sets you can build from open sets and closed sets via countable unions and intersections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) (it turns out there are a lot of these).

The general study of classifying subsets of topological spaces beyond just open and closed is generally viewed as part of **descriptive set theory**.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is closed if and only if $\overline{A}=A$ everything boils down to finding the closure of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb Q$. But $$\overline{\mathbb N\times \mathbb Q}=\overline{\mathbb N}\times \overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb N\times \mathbb R\neq \mathbb N\times \mathbb Q$$ and therefore $\mathbb N\times \mathbb Q$ is not closed.

To check $\overline{\mathbb N}=\mathbb N$ notice $$\overline{\mathbb N}=\mathbb N\cup \mathbb N^\prime$$ where $\mathbb N^\prime$ is the set of limit points of $\mathbb N$ whichy is empy.